# Multi Networking in Lollipop

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-5.0-lollipop, cellular-network

I am working on an app that saves your credentials and logs in to the university wifi automatically when connected to a particular ssid. Everything is working fine. But when mobile data is on and wifi gets connected, the login request is sent through the mobile data (since the wifi connection is not active). 
I read on the documentation and tried this.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)       context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder requestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    requestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(requestBuilder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
        }
    });
}
new LoginTask().execute();
```

This doesn't solve my problem.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
NetworkInfo networkInfo;
Network network;
    for (int i = 0; i < networks.length; i++){               
        network = networks[i];
        networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
        if ((networkInfo.getType() ==     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) && (networkInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))) {
           ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the only thing that's worked for me for an S5 with Marshmallow. I tried the way above at first too with `requestNetwork` (which worked for most phones), but I never received an `onAvailable` callback with the S5 M